# Running Python 3 Script on Apache 2.4 Web Server

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache

I have Apache 2.4 installed and running on localhost. I am trying to get CGI to work through editing httpd.conf so it will be able to run my python scripts.

All I want it to do currently is be able to print "Hello World" so I know it is working.

```
print("hello world")
```

This is a copy of my httpd.conf file as of submitting this post.

```
Define SRVROOT "/apache24ah64"

ServerRoot "${SRVROOT}"


LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>

ServerAdmin admin@example.com
<Directory C:\Apache24\htdocs>
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi py
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks FollowSymLinks ExecCGI

    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error.log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>

      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common

</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>

</IfModule>

<Directory "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule headers_module>
    RequestHeader unset Proxy early
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py

</IfModule>

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>


<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
```

I have looked through the documentation and at a couple of different tutorials but I haven't been able to find what is wrong.

The python script is inside C:\Apache24\htdocs
Python Version 3.7
Apache 2.4

Changes to the httpd.conf file:

1. Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
2. AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
3. LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so

Answer (score 0):

I have a python script running as `index.py` like that:

```
DirectoryIndex index.py

<Directory "/var/www/xyz">
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>
```

I think you have the correct arguments, but they need to be in the `<Directory>` section.

Comment: ```<Directory C:\Apache24\htdocs>
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi py
</Directory>```    I already added that

Comment: I missed that, have you tried putting the path in quotes in the Directory line: "C:\Apache24\htdocs" ?

Comment: Put it in quotes and it still doesn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though.